# JAVA Rest services JSON encoding

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

I have a rest service which returns a list of Dto's one field in dto is localized and is translated to some countries, the problem is when i test it in soap UI i see that special characters are encoded from `Kjøregodtgjørelse` to `Kj&oslash;regodtgj&oslash;relse` here's the code snippet :

```
@Path("user")
@RequestScoped
@RolesAllowed(Roles.REGULAR_USER)
public class UserTravelRest extends RESTEndpoint<UserTravelService > {

    @EJB
    private UserTravelService service;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("travel")
    public List<TravelsDTO> getTravels() throws GeneralException {
        return service.getTravelsForUser();
    }
```

So it's just a simple get which returns dto list which looks like this :

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@XmlRootElement
public class TravelsDTO implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Long id;
    private BigDecimal amount;
    private String displayName;
}
```

displayName is the field which gets encoded.
Should i add some unescaping before returning list in rest service or something else ?

Comment: May i know which soap ui you are using

Comment: Version is 5.3.0

Comment: Ensure that SoapUI is using UTF-8 as mentioned [here](https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-NG/How-to-change-default-encoding-to-UTF-8-for-entire-application/td-p/122935).

Comment: soap ui version 5.3.0 uses JRE version 1.7.0_55 . Make sure you are using  compatible  JDK .If you are using jdk as same version or higher its ok ,else upgrade. Check in docs of Soap UI . For enabling localization in Soap UI as well

Answer (score 1):

There may be an issue with your client. According to the [JSR 339](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jaxrs-2_0-fr-eval-spec/jsr339-jaxrs-2.0-final-spec.pdf?AuthParam=1491902396_cbc39656fdcaab237e5f481e863def0a), UTF-8 should be used by default if no other charset is specified:

> When writing responses, implementations SHOULD respect application-supplied character set metadata and SHOULD use UTF-8 if a character set is not specified by the application or if the application specifies a character set that is unsupported.

As already mentioned in [diginoise's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43341405/1426227), to make sure that your resource method is producing UTF-8 encoded data, you can use:

```java
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to be explicit about the text encoding:

```
@Produces("application/json; charset=UTF-8")
```